# Do electrons go towards higher voltage or lower voltage?

Tags: voltage, current

Can someone clear this up for me once and for all? I feel like Thomas Edison really screwed me when he made everyone believe that current is movement of positive charges.

Do electrons go from high voltage to low voltage or from low voltage to high voltage?

Comment: I thought it was Benjamin Franklin.

Comment: Or JJ Thomson (1856 - 1940)?

Comment: Or the entire 19th-century physics community.

Comment: Your question buries a problem. Things don't have "voltage values" assigned to them. So there isn't a voltage value in the absolute sense where you imagine that points have voltage values, as a property of themselves. Instead, voltage only manifests itself over distance between ***two*** points. I cannot say that the left front corner of my desk is 100 V and the right front corner of my desk is 110 V, resulting in a 10 V difference. It's that there is a 10 V difference between them. The mystery 100 V I added to both is fake. Break yourself of the idea that points have voltages. Tear it down.

Comment: During currents in salt water, the positives move forward, and the negatives move backward, passing each other. (And no electrons are flowing.) How can we even talk about this? Just use a fancy concept called "Amperes."  It's also called "Conventional Current." It's also called "Electric current." When using amperes, we add the backward negative flow to the forward positive flow. Amperes aren't flows of electrons. Amperes CONCEAL the complicated nature of the moving charges. And, amperes always go forward, as if salt water really contained just one type of current, when it really has two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I feel like Thomas Edison really screwed me when he made everyone believe that current is movement of positive charges.

As we're 'clearing things up', let's be very careful in our language.

Current is the movement of charges, both negative and positive.

Current, aka Conventional Current (because its direction is subject to a convention), is defined to flow in the direction the positive charges are moving, and opposite to the direction the negative charges are moving.

In any given medium, there may be several species of particle that carry charge, and are able to move, and so can give rise to a current.

In water, the OH<sup>-</sup> and H<sub>3</sub>O<sup>+</sup> ions are able to move.
In ice however, only the H<sup>+</sup> can move.
In copper sulphate solution, [Cu(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>6</sub>]<sup>2+</sup> and SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup> are mobile
In semiconductors, the holes<sup>1</sup>, and some of the electrons, are able to move
In metals, some of the electrons are free to move.
In a fully developed plasma, all of the electrons, and the bare nuclei, are free to move.

When you do a mesh analysis of a circuit, you label the mesh with current direction arrows. This can be done arbitrarily, and the solution will tell you whether the currents are negative or positive. In any non-trivial mesh, you will have to add and subtract currents, and this would be true regardless of the convention you use for the direction of conventional current.

> Do electrons go from high voltage to low voltage or from low voltage to high voltage?

If by 'high voltage' you mean 'more positive voltage', then a mobile electron would tend to move to a high voltage electrode, as would all other negative charge carriers. Mobile positive charge carriers move to the less positive electrode. So for instance in copper sulphate electrolysis, the copper anode dissolves, as the copper ions move across to the cathode.

---

<sup>1</sup> A hole is just as much of a quantum mechanical particle as an electron, it has mass, velocity, momentum, charge. I'm not saying it is a particle, just if that you model an electron as a particle for conduction purposes, then the same model fits a hole.

Answer (score 4):

Using the electric potential, the potential energy is given by:

$$U = q \times V$$
Where \$q\$ is the charge value of an electron, which is negative: \$q = -1.6\times10^{-19}\,\text{C}\$.

Taking into example two poles of a circuit, having 5 V and 0 V as values:

For 0 V: \$U=0 \$
For 5 V: \$U=5\times(-1.6\times10^{-19})\$ which is a negative value

As a law of nature, everything is attracted to the lower energy potential state ( U(5V) < U(0V) for electrons), and that´s the reason because in this case, electrons move towards the higher voltage possible.

Answer (score 3):

The electric field is defined as pointing from positive to negative. Electrons are repelled from the negative and attracted to the positive, hence they move in the OPPOSITE direction that the electric field is pointing. So I guess you could say electrons want to move from the more negative/less positive voltage to the less negative/more positive voltage.

In short, similar repels and opposites attract. Since electrons are negative, they move away from the negative (which is what you would call the lower voltage). Conversely, electrons are negative and therefore move towards the positive (which is what you would call the higher voltage).

Answer (score 3):

Electrons have, by definition, a negative charge. They are attracted to a positive charge and repelled by a negative one. So, yes, electrons flow from negative to positive charge. We think of them that way when studying physics and electrochemistry.

‘Conventional current’ on the other hand flows from positive to negative. This, er, *convention* predates electron theory, and in fact originated with Ben Franklin.

Obligatory XKCD:

[image]

Comment: Poor Randall, his cartoon is wrong. Or at best, it teaches a widespread physics-misconception. It's based on the false idea that electric currents are flows of electrons.  They're not. Not unless you're a 1940s radar-repair tech, who was taught  1) never question the teacher, and 2) vacuum tubes and metal wires are based on electron-flows only (and we won't confuse you by mentioning that electrons never flow through battery electrolyte, or through the damp ground, or through leaky insulators, or through salt water, or through human beings... )  Protons can flow, so, amperes are charge flows.

Answer (score 0):

Just think of the positive terminal on a battery as the "high electron density side"

Electrons normally force other electrons away and usually congregate on edges and sharp points... Kind of like penguins.